# video extract using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

My task to extract the video of 1min before using after trigger here trigger is passing when->it contains datetimeformat(190425132148).I need to convert this format into minute and subtract formatted minute with 1min(21-1) therfore result will be 20:00 the video play from 20:00 and ends in 21:00 exactly 1minute video have to take and save in separate folder but .and I record video for every 5 minutes.I have no idea about this extraction.
Below is the code,

```
   tm exampleTime() 
   {

struct tm tm;

strptime("2019-04-09 14:28:16", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);

return tm;
}

int main() {

    struct tm when;
when = exampleTime();

VideoCapture obj;
Mat frame;

obj.open(recordVideo->getVideoFile(when));

while(obj.read(frame)) {

    imshow("A", frame);

    char exitKeyPress = (char)waitKey(500);   //to terminate
    if( exitKeyPress == ESC_KEY_PRESSED )
        break;
}
obj.release();
```

I need to take the previous 1minute of the video

Comment: You can always use [get](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939) function of the VideoCapture object or the [set](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c) with the property [CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704da7c2fa550ba270713fca1405397b90ae0). For example, use set to jump to minute 20, then loop using get to see if you are before minute 21 then set again to jump 5 minutes and so on

Comment: @api55..how to extract that event video

Comment: create a videoWriter object and save the frames you got from the other file which you need

Comment: using videowriter create function.

Comment: @api55 Thankyou very much